# What format does a partition have to be in order to boot linux off of it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partitioning

I am using disk utility to partition an external hard disk. My intention is to boot linux off of the partition. However, I am unsure of which format to make the partition. Disk Utility in OS X only allows Mac OS X Journaled, Mac OS X, FAT, exFAT, and free space.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it unformatted for now (or as you call 'free space' as your disk utility can not format it into ext2/3/4 which is typically used for Linux).

While you are installing Linux from a Live CD/DVD, it can be taken care by Installer (eg ubuntu Live CD can format the partition in one of many choices)

Comment: When installing, I'd recommend ext4.

Comment: +1 for ext4, am using it on my SSD (with journaling disabled) as well as regular HDD

Answer (score 0):

Both the supported partition types (Superfloppy, DOS Primary, GPT) and bootable filesystems depend on your bootloader.